# Groovy parameter "String..."

Tags: groovy

I'm in the midst of implementing unit tests for a web application and I've come across this piece of code (and some others) that have a parameter as "String..." I'm not sure what the "..." means, if anything at all, as I can't find any explanation anywhere.

```
public static List<User> getUsersForGroups(String... dns) {
    Set<String> members = getMembers(dns)
    return members.collect{ getUser(it) }.findAll{ it }.sort{ User u -> "$u.lastName  $u.firstName"}
}
```

Comment: Same as in Java, it's a varargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Java feature called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), [Groovy also supports it](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_varargs). It lets the method accept multiple parameters without making the caller package them into a data structure first. The arguments get bundled into an array before being passed into the method:

```
groovy:000> def foo(String... stuff) {
groovy:001>   println(stuff.class)
groovy:002>   for (s in stuff) {
groovy:003>     println(s)
groovy:004>   }}
===> true
groovy:000> foo('a','b','c','d')
class [Ljava.lang.String;
a
b
c
d
===> null
groovy:000> foo('q')
class [Ljava.lang.String;
q
===> null
```

`class [Ljava.lang.String;` means it's an array (as opposed to a `java.util.ArrayList`).

Comment: Just to add to the answer: String... is in Java usable for methods and means a String[] with a special flag for varargs and special handling through the compiler to automatically create the array. In Groovy a String[] as last parameter (the only valid position for varargs) is always handled as varargs, Thus in Groovy String... is just an alias for String[]